# How to make right side in css oblique?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make background for menu list item looks as a tab, how can this be done in CSS and to add icon beside it
[image: As this example]

CSS

```
#cdnavheader .activeMenuItem span {
background-position: 100% -145px;
color: #2d83ab;
padding: 12px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #fff;
background-color: #2d489b;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
```

}

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried something? StackOverflow is not a web service provider.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: StackOverflow not provide exact code.. you might be help if you put your codes. but if not. StackOverflow not help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a pseudo and transform:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;/* fallback*/
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  padding: 1em 3em 1em 2em; 
}

a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 120%;
  height: 200%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius:inherit;
  transform: skew(35deg)
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav><a href="#"> some link</a>
  <a href="#"> some link</a>
  <a href="#"> some link</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a zero height DIV with a big border:

```css
.tab {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 0px; 
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab"></div>
```

More info here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: OP is looking for a rounded triangle. The one you provided has sharp edges. I think SVG would be needed here.